# SQLAlchemy multiple foreight keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Can someone explain the proper way to do this :

```
class Bracket(Base):
    __tablename__     = 'weekly_bracket'
    bracket_1A_winner = Column( Integer, nullable = False )
    bracket_1B_winner = Column( Integer, nullable = False )
    bracket_2_winner  = Column( Integer, nullable = False )
    handle            = Column( String(250),ForeignKey('user.site_handle') )
    user_id           = Column( Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key = True )
    user              = relationship( User )
```

Answer (score 1):

In regard to multiple foreign keys, you can check out [Multiple Join Paths](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths) in the docs for further information. That will explain in more detail what is going on.

For your immediate concern, there are some problems with the class. You're primary key is set to a foreign key. This is probably not what you are trying to to. The table name in `relationship()` should be the name of you User class, as string. You can also specify the foreign key in the relationship() call. Try this:

```
class Bracket(Base):
    __tablename__     = 'weekly_bracket'

    id = Column ( Integer, primary_key = True )
    bracket_1A_winner = Column( Integer, nullable = False )
    bracket_1B_winner = Column( Integer, nullable = False )
    bracket_2_winner  = Column( Integer, nullable = False )
    handle            = Column( String(250),ForeignKey('user.site_handle') )
    user_id           = Column( Integer, ForeignKey('user.id') )
    user              = relationship( 'User', foreign_keys=[user_id] )
```

In your case, I don't see where you need multiple foreign keys here. If you had two users, with two relationships, this would be a cause for multiple foreign keys. For example:

```
class Bracket(Base):
    __tablename__     = 'weekly_bracket'

    id = Column ( Integer, primary_key = True )
    bracket_1A_winner = Column( Integer, nullable = False )
    bracket_1B_winner = Column( Integer, nullable = False )
    bracket_2_winner  = Column( Integer, nullable = False )
    handle            = Column( String(250),ForeignKey('user.site_handle') )
    bracket1_user_id  = Column( Integer, ForeignKey('user.id') )
    bracket2_user_id  = Column( Integer, ForeignKey('user.id') )

    bracket1_user     = relationship( 'User', foreign_keys=[bracket1_user_id] )
    bracket2_user     = relationship( 'User', foreign_keys=[bracket2_user_id] )
```

As @ChristopherPearson mentioned, you don't need an 'id' field acting as a primary_key(I deleted my incorrect comment). Using the user_id as the primary key is ok because the user_id field will also be unique. But if you want a user to have more than one bracket, that relationship won't work for long.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I only want to have one bracket per user.  That is why I was thinking of using the user_id as the primary key.

Comment: @ryanday, not true, a primary key can be a foreign key from a different table.  In fact, this is quite common.  Consider the case where you have a link table to facilitate a many-to-many relationship.  Both columns in the link table would be foreign keys from the two linked tables and also primary keys (composite primary key).

Comment: @ChristopherPearson uhg of course!  I answered that too quickly. Composites on FKs are obviously ok. There would still be issues there if a user wanted more than one bracket, but at that point I'm really putting too many assumptions on the design.